# How to add pagination to table created usign javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a table from javascript and I want to add a pagination to this table. Is there any way to do this?

```
output += '<table class="table">';

//Some other code

info.fields.forEach(function (field) {    
      if (infoData.hasOwnProperty(field.key)) {
             var data = infoData[field.key];
             data = (data == null) ? "-" : data;
             output += '<td>' + data + '</td>';  
      } else {
             output += '<td>-</td';
      }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a light weighted javascript library [datatable](https://datatables.net/).

**EDIT**

Yes, there are many library which can help you but I personally use datatable.

**HOW TO USE:**

Add library's [css](http:////cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css) and [js](http:////cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js).

When creating table add id to the table `<table id="tableId">` after that initialize the datatable like below.

```
$('#tableId').DataTable();
```

**NOTE:**
don't forget to add css and js file and first create table then initialize .DataTable().

For more datatable options [click here](https://datatables.net/manual/options)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how he can integrate this plugin to his code. That would be better IMO

Comment: I have found many datatable libraries but I don't know how to use them with my js code.